# how can i take the value of a vector 3 from a liste of vector 3

Tags: vector

```
foreach (Vector3 posit in position){
    if (ang){

        float a = Random.Range (0.0f, 60.0f);
        //Vector3 p1= new Vector3((position[i-1].x)+(ra*cos(a)),0.0f,(position[i-1].z)+(ra*Sin(a)));


    //  position.Add(p1);



    }
    else
    {
        //Quaternion.Angle=60.0f;
        float a = Random.Range (120.0f, 290.0f);


    }
    Vector3 p1 = new Vector3((posit[i-1].x)+(ra*(Mathf cos(a))), posit[i].y,(posit[i-1].z)+(ra*(Mathf Sin(a))));


    position.Add(p1);

    ang=!ang;
    //return(pos);
    i++;
}

return(position[i]);
```

}

Comment: By reading this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `foreach`, you'll want to use `for`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < position.Count; i++) {
    Vector3 posit = position[i];
    ...
}
```

This way, you'll be able to access the previous position using `position[i-1]`.

Keep in mind, however, that this won't work if `i == 0` because you can't go less than zero, so you'll want to add some checks to ensure `i > 0` before using `position[i-1]`.